# A Motley Crew of Carolers

Tags: visual, seasonal, movies

A motley crew of carolers has come to sing some songs. Who are they and what is their underlying message?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hidden message says:

> **MERRY CHRISTMAS!**

The carollers are all (with the exception of the last, of course) primarily:

> *characters from festive films*. The raised studs upon (or behind) which they stand indicate the lengths of their names, and the **red** studs indicate highlighted letters that contribute towards the message. In all, these characters are:
>
>  **M**ARV, K**E**VIN and HA**RRY** from [*Home Alone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_Alone);
>
>  [The] [GRIN**CH**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_the_Grinch_Stole_Christmas_(2000_film)),
>
>  **R**ALPH**I**E from [*A Christmas Story*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Christmas_Story) with 'The Lamp': a table lamp in the shape of a woman's leg wearing a fishnet stocking (a MacGuffin from the movie),
>
>  JACK **S**KELLING**T**ON from [*The Nightmare Before Christmas*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nightmare_Before_Christmas);
>
>  JOHN **M**CCL**A**NE from the [*Die Hard*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_McClane) series,
>
>  and (one who *definitely does exist* outside of movies...) **S**ANTA!
>
>  Reading off those highlighted red-letter studs gives us the pertinent festive message **MERRY CHRISTMAS**!

Comment: Nice! And just for completion what is that thing next to rot13(Enycuvr)?

Comment: @cap Done! And I wish you a REDACTED! :)

Comment: perfect, and I wish you one as well