# PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 21): Color of the Bells

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, language, anagram, music, seasonal

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2022](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7414/37714). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.

[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119081/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-20-the-christmas-gift) [<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119107/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-22-santas-sleigh-route)</sub>

---

[A Motley Crew of Carolers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114203/a-motley-crew-of-carolers) comes to your door and starts singing songs. Beholden by the beauty, you are suddenly stricken with synesthesia. Sensing a deeper meaning, you carefully transcribe the colorful notes.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

***What messages lie hidden in the music?***

Comment: Colors [should be accessible](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/khroma/vignettes/tol.html#bright) but let me know if you don't see six colors as well as black.

Comment: Did you use Musescore 4 :D?

Comment: @Stevo Yes. How could you tell?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, let's identify the tunes:

> Jingle Bells
>  Have Yourself A Merry Little Christmas
>  Here Comes Santa Claus
>  Rudolf The Red-Nosed Reindeer
>  Frosty The Snowman
>  Feliz Navidad
>  Happy Xmas (War Is Over)

Now, there's something not quite right about those scores:

> There's no time signature on any of them, and the bars aren't consistent lengths.
>  In fact, it looks like there is one bar per word of the song title, with one note per letter in each bar.

> Extracting the corresponding letter for each note and sorting by colour gives us:
>  Light blue: JOLENUOYXE
>  Yellow: NEEFRIHHCTEONWHA
>  Dark Blue: ELVECESOENAV
>  Green: BATOULNENA
>  Pink: SARTMCHRERMYSI
>  Purple: FELIZNAVIDAD

Finally:

> Those are all anagrams of Merry Christmas in different languages:
>  Light blue: Joyeux Noel (French)
>  Yellow: Frohe Weihnachten (German)
>  Dark Blue: Vesele Vanoce (Czech)
>  Green: Buon Natale (Italian)
>  Pink: Merry Christmas (English)
>  Purple: Feliz Navidad (Spanish)