# PSE Advent Calendar 2022 (Day 23): Christmas Classifieds

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, seasonal

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2022](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7414/37714). The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.

[<kbd>< Previous Door</kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119107/pse-advent-calendar-2022-day-22-santas-sleigh-route) [<kbd>Next Door ></kbd>](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/119121/81979)</sub>

---

I've finally done it! The directors have approved the print run unaware that this year a grinchly message has been hidden in the otherwise festive classifieds page. Can you find it?

[image: Christmas Classifieds - Advert Page]

Note: This puzzle is much more fun printed out. Happy to send any by mail if needed :)

Comment: @Stevo i assume they just misclicked on the reason - it's usually To Reward An Existing Answer or something like that - but all the Advent Calendar puzzles give a bounty to the answerer as a special Chirstmas prize

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First we print it out

> [image]

Then we notice

> the red words "1 Mountain fold red line" and the red lines.

So we

> fold along the red lines such that they form an outer (mountain) ridge.
>  [image]

Then we notice

> the cyan "2 valley fold" and a cyan line so we fold along the cyan line such that it forms an inner (valley) ridge.
>  [image]

Then we see

> the green "3 valley fold (from GLOP's reflection overlapping EPIC) along" and a green line so we do so.
>  [image]

Then there is

> purple "4 valley fold" so we do that too.
>  [image]

Now we see

> orange "5 cut" and some scissors and an orange squiggly line. We take our scissors and cut along the orange line. Then we unfold and find
>  [image]
>  a beautiful snowflake!

Then we see

> in the center "exit maze here!", in the top-left "Start Here!", and in the top-right "Don't cross" with an arrow pointing to a red-white striped bar. Looks like we have ourselves a maze!

Following it

> from start to exit, we trace a path that crosses several symbolic images: Christ, Massachusetts, percent, a minus sign, cent, an 'h', some apps, a mean face emoji, an 's', an 'a', a lit candle, a bottle, a minus sign, a bot, a drill bit, an 'm', and an oar.

Interpreting them

> as a rebus, we get **CHRIST + MASS + PERCENT - CENT + H + APPS + MEAN + S + A + LIT + BOTTLE - BOT + BIT + M + OAR**

or

> our grinchy message:
> **[Christmas perhaps means a little bit more!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0v53Z3QHso)**

Comment: Great solve to a great puzzle, really well explained with the step-by-step diagrams - nice work! :)